# assigning button value value provided by model in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a button for each item that is returned from my model and assign the value of the button to the column "collegeOf".  My buttons display the first part of it "College" but it should be something like "College of liberal arts and sciences".  I can't figure out why the value is getting truncated after the first word.  Below is my code for my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<KU_PLAN_DEV.Models.TRACK_INFO>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "All Degree Tracks";
}

<h2>Kutztown University Degree Tracks</h2>

<div class="jumbotronAll">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {   
        <br />        
        Html.BeginForm("Index", "AllTracks");
        {
            <input type="submit" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.collegeOf)       class="AllTracksButtons" />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Try `<input type="submit" value=@item.collegeOf ...>`

Comment: Surround Stephens answer above with single quotes around the value.

Comment: it does the same thing

Comment: @user3255899, If the value of `item.collegeOf` is `"College of liberal arts and sciences"` then `<input type="submit" value='@item.collegeOf' />` will create `<input type="submit" value="College of liberal arts and sciences"/>`. chconger is correct. The quotes are required if the value contains spaces.

Comment: The previous comments are correct.  You should also try using Html.Raw instead of DisplayFor